# Covariant derivatives are tensors?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra, tangent-bundle

First of all, I know the fact that exists at least three objects which can be view as the same depending on the context and usage. But suppose then the following:

#### I) General Points

Given a *connection* $\nabla_{(\cdot)}(\cdot)$ on a manifold, then we can explore the notion of *Parallel Transport*. Given the realization of the geometrical meaning of a parallel transport we can define a notion of a direction derivative $\nabla_{\bf{X}}\bf{Y}$.

Ocurred to me some points, though:

> $1)$ In a coordinate chart we can write the directional derivarive as:
>
> $$ \nabla_{\textbf{X}}\textbf{Y} = \Big\{X^{\nu}\Big[ \partial_{\nu}Y^{\alpha} + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\hspace{1.5mm}\mu\hspace{0.2mm}\nu}Y^{\mu}\Big]\Big\}\vec{\partial}_{\alpha} \equiv \Big(X^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha}\Big)\vec{\partial}_{\alpha}   \tag{1}$$

> $2)$ From General Relativity books and (some) Differential Geometry literature we call *Covariant Derivative* the components:
>
> $$ \nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha} = \partial_{\nu}Y^{\alpha} + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\hspace{1.5mm}\mu\hspace{0.2mm}\nu}Y^{\mu} \tag{2}$$
>
> We note that this so-called "covariant derivative" is no more than a part of the components directional derivative $(1)$, i.e, is just $\Big(X^{\nu}\nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha}\Big)$ without the vector components $X^{\nu}$.

> $3)$ From a simple comparison we can speculate that the whole symbol $\nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha}$ could given rise to another object such as:
>
> $$\nabla\textbf{Y} = \nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha} (some\hspace{1.5mm} tensor\hspace{1.5mm} basis)\tag{3}$$

> $4)$ From elementary tensor calculus, which is famously a non-rigorous subject, we can prove that such symbols $\nabla_{\nu}Y^{\alpha}$ indeed transforms as a tensor field:
>
> $$\nabla_{\nu '}Y^{\alpha '} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha '}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\gamma}}{\partial x^{\nu '}}\nabla_{\gamma}Y^{\beta} \tag{4}$$

We note that $4)$ is a $(1,1)-$tensor field, in fact. Now, a $(1,1)-$tensor is an object that lives in a tensor product $T_{p}M \otimes T_{p}M^{*}$, where $T_{p}M$ and $T_{p}M^{*}$ are the tangent and cotangent spaces, and therefore is an object just like:

$$ \mathrm{T} = t^{\mu}\hspace{0.3mm}_{\nu} \vec{\partial}_{\mu} \otimes dx^{\nu} \tag{5}$$

and it's components transforms as:

$$ t^{\alpha '}\hspace{0.3mm}_{\nu '} = \frac{\partial x^{\alpha '}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\gamma '}}t^{\beta}\hspace{0.3mm}_{\gamma}  \tag{6}$$

Therefore from the arguments presented and the general realization of $(5)$ and $(6)$, we can properly say that the object $\nabla\textbf{Y}$ is written as:

$$\nabla\textbf{Y} = \nabla_{\nu}Y^{\mu} \vec{\partial}_{\mu} \otimes dx^{\nu} \tag{7}$$

#### II) My Doubt

Regardless the chosen basis, a tensor (more generally a tensor field) is a multilinear function defined by:

$$ \mathrm{T}: T_{p}M \times....\times T_{p}M \times T_{p}M^{*}\times....\times T_{p}M^{*}  \to \mathbb{R} \tag{8}$$

Thefore, the object $(5)$ is a object that acts like:

$$ \mathrm{T}: T_{p}M \times T_{p}M^{*} \to \mathbb{R} \tag{9}$$

The problem is that, I'm sure that the object that transforms as $(6)$ is something that acts like $(9)$. But I'm not sure if the covariant derivative is something that acts like $(9)$. Follwing my reasoning I would said yes, but I never see a covariant derivative acting on a vector and spitting a scalar. So:

**A covariant derivative is the object $(7)$? In other words, a covariant derivative is a $(1,1)-$ tensor field?**

Comment: If $Y$ is a $(1,0)$-tensor field (i.e. a vector field), then $\nabla Y$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor field.
Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz Precisely. The thing is, I've never see a diagram like this $\nabla Y: T_{p}M \times T_{p}M^{*} \to \mathbb{R}$ in a reference.

Comment: The tensor field $\nabla Y$ acts on the tangent bundle rather than the tangent spaces i.e. instead of what you just wrote we have $\nabla Y:TM\otimes TM^*\to C^\infty(M)$

Comment: @DanielPlácido The appropriate description would be the action on (co)vectors $\nabla Y:TM\otimes T^*M\to\mathbb{R}$, or alternately on sections $\nabla Y:\mathfrak{X}M\times\mathfrak{X}^*M\to C^\infty M$.

Comment: @Kajelad I understood the second action, but the first one I did not. I mean, why $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $C^{\infty}(M)$?

Comment: @M.N.Raia: think about what $TM \otimes T^* M$ is as a set: it's the union of $T_p M \otimes T_p^*M$ over all $p \in M.$ Thus a single element of $TM \otimes T^* M$ is just a single element of $T_p M \otimes T_p^* M$ for *a single* point $p$. The only way to meaningfully plug this into $\nabla Y$ is to contract it with $\nabla Y_p$ to get a real number.